# my jquery var is logging something odd

Tags: jquery, object, logging, console, var

I am somewhat new to jquery.

Can any one tell me what's wrong with this?

```
var l = $(target)+".thumb".length;
```

The console log returns this:

```
[object Object]6
```

I have the "target" var set up ahead of the "l" var (along with another var) like this:

```
var target = $(this).parent();
var n = $(".thumb").outerWidth(true);
var l = $(target)+".thumb".length;
```

I'm not sure what "[obbject Object] in the log means.

Comment: `[object Object]` means you have an object, ie something that isn't just a string or an int (or other primitive type).  In this case it's a jquery object.  Exactly what are you trying to do with the `target`?

Comment: If you want to know what it is, then learn how to debug your code and inspect the variable.  You can put the keyword `debugger;` directly above your code and the browser will go into debugging mode for you.  Or you could add `console.log($(target))` to see what it is (don't use `alert()` as it will show `[Object]` again).

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var target = $(this).parent();
var l = $(target)+".thumb".length;
```

`target` is object at first line, the second line replace by

```
var l = target+".thumb".length;
```

maybe ok

Comment: Because in *this* case, `target` will be a DOM element, which is... an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` rather than concat string to get length.

```js
$("#btnTest").on("click", function() {
  var target = $(this).parent();
  var n = $(".thumb").outerWidth(true);
  var l = $(target).find(".thumb").length;
  console.log(l);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='thumb'></div>
  <input type='button' id='btnTest' value='Test' />
  <div class='thumb'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This assumes `.thumb` is a child of the event's parent.  Without any html or further clarification from OP, this is just a guess (a possibility, but still a guess).  It's just as likely that the thumbs are in a completely different location in the html.  Who knows?  OP knows, but isn't telling.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.